# Why does the kobold inventor in Tomb of Annihilation reference Appendix A?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, tomb-of-annihilation

The Weapon Invention action of the **kobold inventor** in *Tomb of Annihilation* references Appendix A in its weapon invention action for *pot of rot grubs*:

> *Rot Grub Pot.* The kobold throws a clay pot into a 5-foot-square space within 20 feet of it, and it breaks open on impact. A **swarm of rot grubs** (see appendix A) emerges from the shattered pot and remains a hazard in that square.

However, appendix A only contains the two new backgrounds. Is this a typo, or did I just miss something? Also, if the stat block isn't there, where would I find the stat block?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

#### It is referring to “Appendix A: Assorted Beasts” in *Volo’s Guide to Monsters*.

The Kobold Inventor was first published in *Volo’s Guide to Monsters* (pg. 166), and the stat block there references “appendix A”:

[image: Photo of the Volo’s Guide kobold inventor stat block referencing appendix A]

> *Rot Grub Pot.* The kobold throws a clay pot into a 5-foot-square space within 20 feet of it, and it breaks open on impact. A **swarm of rot grubs** (see appendix A) emerges from the shattered pot and remains a hazard in that square.

And if you check appendix A in *Volo’s Guide* (pg. 208), you will find the stat block for a swarm of rot grubs. They obviously lifted this stat block straight out of *Volo’s Guide* when putting together *Tomb of Annihilation*.

The kobold inventor was republished in *Monsters of the Multiverse*, and the “see appendix A” was replaced with something a little less helpful:

> **Rot Grub Pot.** The kobold throws a clay pot into a 5-foot-square space within 20 feet of it, and it breaks open on impact. A swarm of rot grubs *(in this book)* emerges from the shattered pot and remains a hazard in that square.